java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 7372000F
I have a application that reads data from a XML file from Online Street Map. I parse the individual XML elements to a HashMap with the data.
I try to write the new parse data into smaller chunks in binary files, but I get a java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 7372000F at method getAllTagBoundsFromBinaryFile().
I have parsed each XML element from the abstract class called Tag that extends HashMap. So each object written to the binary file should implement Serializable: 
public abstract class Tag<E extends Enum<E>> extends HashMap<E, Object>
I create the chunks of binary files and write a TagBound (that extends Tag) that represent an area of the Online Street Map in latitude and longitude:
public class XMLWriter {
    private String directoryPath = "src/main/resources/chunks/";
    // A static class "ChunkFiles" that handles/stores .bin file paths and their TagBound
    private static ChunkFiles chunkFiles = new ChunkFiles();
    private static int chunkId = 0;

    public XMLWriter(TagBound bounds) {
        initChunkFiles(bounds);    
    }

    public void initChunkFiles(TagBound bounds) {   
        // Split the bounds into smaller chunks
        for (TagBound parentChunk : Chunk.getQuadrants(bounds).values()) {
            Chunk childChunk = new Chunk(parentChunk); 
            
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                // Get one of the four quadrants in the chunk
                TagBound child = childChunk.getQuadrant(j);

                // Append the chunk files TagBound to the chunk path: HashMap<TagBound, String>
                chunkFiles.appendChunkFile(child, directoryPath + "chunk_" + chunkId + ".bin");
                // Create the chunk file
                createBinaryChunkFile(directoryPath + "chunk_" + chunkId + ".bin", child);
                chunkId++;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createBinaryChunkFile(String path, TagBound bound){
      try{
          File file = new File(path);
          if (!file.exists()){
             file.createNewFile();
          }
       ObjectOutputStream oos = new AppendableObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream (path, true));
            oos.writeObject(bound);
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }

     private static class AppendableObjectOutputStream extends ObjectOutputStream implements Serializable {
          public AppendableObjectOutputStream(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
            super(out);
          }

          @Override
          protected void writeStreamHeader() throws IOException {}
    }
...

I then try to read the TagBound objects from the binary files:
    public static List<TagBound> getAllTagBoundsFromBinaryFile() {
        List<TagBound> tagBounds = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String path : chunkFiles.getChunkFilePaths()) {
            try (FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(path);
                 ObjectInputStream ostream = new ObjectInputStream(fstream)) {
                while (true) {
                    TagBound tagBound = (TagBound) ostream.readObject();
                    tagBounds.add(tagBound);
                }
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return tagBounds;
    }


0x7372 is ASCII. You are getting out of sync somewhere. NB if (!file.exists()){ file.createNewFile(); } is a complete waste of time and space here. Remove it.

In fact 0x7372 is "IH".

You have mismatched write+reads by appending a new object output stream for each write, but you only use one object input stream to read everything. Thus the second attempt at readObject will be corrupt as it reads the header of the second ObjectOutputStream not the content of the second tag you wrote. Serialize just a List<TagBound> in one stream .

@DuncG That would cause ‘invalid type code: AC’, not this message. Same exception, different cause.
